# How can I relate these two sentences

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, conjunctions, transitions

I wrote:

> The extraction command was described in the previous section. For example, according to this command, the content of *exData* may be enclosed in an Xml node whose label is specified in the extraction command. **or / Also / Moreover / As another example / in another command / In addition**, a regular expression may be applied to *exData* in order to extract and store only specific parts of it.

I want to mention another case where the extraction command is employed. Maybe "or" is the simplest choice but it makes the sentence too long. Then, I don't know which alternative word to use here.

Comment: How about "Alternatively,"?

Comment: @Mick thank for a new word. It seems good, but maybe it is not an alternative, it is just another usage of extraction command.

Comment: If the regular expression is an optional argument, then *additionally* might be more appropriate.

Comment: FWIW, *Alternatively* was my first thought as well, and then I realized that a better approach could be rewriting the whole thing, making it clear the these two cases are only examples.

Comment: @DamkerngT. How?

Comment: @Mick *additionally* seems good :)!

Comment: @DamkerngT. Agreed. Concrete examples are best. Don't just *tell*, *show* as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to write

"Additionally, a regular expression may be applied to exData to extract and store only specific parts of it."

Unless the intention is that that be an alternative, as opposed to an additional possibility, in which case I would write

"Alternatively, a regular expression may be applied to exData to extract and store only specific parts of it."

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, most of your examples, plus the ones mentioned in the comments, are acceptable.  The only caveat is that it's considered poor style to start a sentence with "Or".

> ... in the extraction command. *Also*, a regular expression may ...
>
> ... in the extraction command. *Moreover*, a regular expression may ...
>
> ... in the extraction command. *Alternately*, a regular expression may ...
>
> ... in the extraction command. *In another command*, a regular expression may ...
>
> ... in the extraction command. *In addition*, a regular expression may ...

I'm good with any of these.  The only one that seems out of place is "In another example", but only because you're describing a *different way* to use the command and not just a second example of the same use of the command.

Comment: thank you, however I didn't "or" as the first sentence but the conjunction. if you think that the sentence is okay with "or", please say

Comment: It's ok with "or", it's just better not to start a sentence with a conjunction.  But, still, many do.  :)